# Image clustering from many number and char pictures , group similar ones together

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-learn, neural-network, cluster-analysis

I have a lot of pictures which content are one of 
 `0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`, like below:

[image]

There are ten thousand pictures, and I don't want to label them by myself. So I tried to use sklearn to cluster them.

My plan:

1. choose a sklearn clustering model, such as Kmeans
2. since `1,l,I`  `c,C`  `o,O`  `s,S` `x,X` `v,V` `z,Z` are similar, I can set a lower `n_cluster` parameter, such as 56.
3. pad all image to same size, but position random(I think this may lead a good result).
4. after cluster done, I can mark the label(1~56) to real char. Then can use this dataset to train a classifier.

---

### But dream is beautiful, fact is hard.

My code:

```
from sklearn import cluster
data = load('data.pkl', '.')

#data.shape
#(103083, 76, 70)

k_means = cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=56, n_jobs=-1)
k_means.fit(data.reshape((data.shape[0], -1)))

# print top 10 image which label by 25
for i in data[np.where(k_means.labels_==25)[0][:10]]:
    plt.figure(figsize=(1,1)), plt.imshow(i, 'gray')
    plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
```

Output:

[image]

It looks like kmeans only determined by positions(label 25 are all middle right).
I am trying other models now(not include neuralnetwork), but many of them don't have `n_job` parameter(for parallel processing), are very slow. And I guess the results may like `kmeans` too. So I am here to ask a proper solution for such case.

Comment: How is the comparison performed ? What similarity score ?

Answer (score 0):

If I was to do this, I would

- label by hand a few samples of each character (say 4, about 250 images),
- perform automatic classification to the nearest neighbor,
- in case there is a doubt on classification, suggest the closest classes and request a manual confirm. A doubt is raised when the difference of similarity to the best cluster and the second best cluster exceeds the estimated cluster size.

For increased safety, after this first training step you could check the outliers in every cluster.

Answer (score 0):

K-means and pretty much every clustering algorithm will never compare adjacent pixels. Because there is no such adjacency in vectors. So **clustering algorithms can't do this on the pixels**.

Even most classification algorithms will have a hard time on the raw data. And clearly, **you should do classification, not clustering**.

If you want 10-years-ago results, then carefully design some features such as edge features, and **use good features rather than pixels**.

If you want state of the art classification performance on such data, use deep learning.